# SOAP with attachment, Android

Tags: http-post

How can I call SOAP WebService using HTTPPOST and adding ATTACHMENT?

For example in this message:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <v:Header />
    <v:Body>
        <CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/" >
            <Celsius i:type="d:string">55</Celsius>
        </CelsiusToFahrenheit>
    </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```